# Setting the value for the textfield using config which is inside fieldcontainer

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am unable to set the value for the textfield which is inside fieldcontainer. I want to set the value and other config for the "textfield" which is inside the "fieldcontainer". So basically i set the configuration for the textfield which i receive from the server, like for example : allowBank: true , maxlength: 4, value: 'Hello World' i get from the server and want to supply it to the textdfield which is inside my custom control which is fieldcontainer. All other configuration is applied except for the value config using the built in textConfig. Below is my code:

```
Ext.define('PTextField', { extend: 'Ext.form.FieldContainer',
            alias: 'widget.ptextfield',
            requires: ['Ext.form.TextField', 'Ext.Img'],
            width: 170,
            fieldLabel: 'Empty Label',
            labelAlign: 'top',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            BLANK_IMAGE_URL: '',


            constructor: function (config) {
                this.callParent(arguments);


                Ext.apply(this.down('textfield'), this.textConfig);
                Ext.apply(this.down('image'), this.imgConfig);


            }, // eo function constructor




            initComponent: function () {
                var me = this;
                this.textBox = this.createTextField();
                this.imageBox = this.createImagefield();
                this.items = [this.imageBox, this.textBox];
                this.callParent(arguments);
            }, //eo initComponent
            createTextField: function () { return {xtype: 'textfield'} },
            createImagefield: function () { return { xtype: 'image', height: 20, width: 20} }
        });

var fname = Ext.create('PTextField', {
            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
            textConfig: { value: 'Hello World', allowBlank: false, readOnly: true,     maxLength: 4, width: 100 },
            imgConfig: { src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png' }
        });

fname.render(Ext.getBody());
```

I am using extjs 4.1.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply create the textfield and image using your configs. Then define your items array using the created objects, like this:

```
initComponent: function() { 
    var me = this,
        textfield = Ext.widget('textfield', me.textConfig),
        image = Ext.widget('image', me.imgConfig);

    me.items = [textfield, image];
    me.callParent(arguments); 
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify your code to something like that:

Remove whole constructor() function. you don't need it.

Rewrite `initComponent()` function for your fieldset as:

```
initComponent: function() {
   var me = this;

   Ext.apply(me, items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      value: me.textConfig.value,
      .... 
   }, {
      xtype: 'image',
      src: me.imageConfig.src,
      ... 
   }]);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why the other config like allowBlank,maxLength being applied using the constructor but the only thing that is not being applied to the field is just value:'hello world'.

Comment: You can put any config using my approach. I think it's simpler

Comment: I wanted the constructor because i wanted to set the config (the ones coming from the server in the form of textConfig, which ones will come i am not aware.) on the textfield, so i didn't wanted to do mapping like value: me.textConfig.value,  for all the configs of textfield.

Comment: You can do this too. Just do this inside initComponent. There is no constructor method according to ExtJs doc. initComponent IS constuctor

Comment: Ok, done that but the same result.still the value config is not being applied, below is my code.
initComponent: function () {
var me = this;
Ext.apply(me, { items: [{
xtype: 'textfield'
}, {
xtype: 'image',
height: 20, 
width: 20
}]
});
                
this.callParent(arguments);
Ext.apply(this.down('textfield'), this.textConfig);
Ext.apply(this.down('image'), this.imgConfig);
},

Comment: Are you sure this.down() returns proper reference?

Comment: Yes i just did a copy paste of my code in Firebug console in a page that has extjs loaded. My concern is all other config is applied only value is not applied to the textdfield.

Comment: value might be special... and require calling setValue() method directly... I'm not sure though

Comment: @nilesh Add `console.log(this.down('textfield'))` right before `Ext.apply(this.down('textfield'), this.textConfig)` what does it return?